# User Fill in for Adobe forms

Tags: ms-word, adobe

I am using Adobe life cycle designer to create docs in my application....I have all my documents in word and I use the export to option in Adobe Life cycle designer and i get the document converted and now I need to have a user fill in the exported document..so can some one please suggest me how this would go and we use the java script behind....

Answer (score 0):

You could have them fill the form in Adobe land, then use the scripting method exportData to get the form data as XML, then inject that XML into your Word docx as a custom xml part.

From there, Word will use the XML in any content controls bound to it.